# SQL How to Update only first Row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL.
I have table with some elements. In last column there is 'Y' or 'N' letter. I need command which Select only first that match (I mean where last column is 'N') and change it on 'Y'.

My idea:

```
UPDATE Table SET Checked='Y' 
WHERE (SELECT Checked FROM Table WHERE Checked='N' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1) = 'N'
```

But it changes 'N' to 'Y' in every row.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is query

```
UPDATE Table SET Checked='Y' 
WHERE ID =(SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Checked='N' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 32):

### Why it didn't work

Others have answered the *how*, but you really need to understand *why* this was wrong:

```
UPDATE Table SET Checked='Y' WHERE (
  SELECT Checked FROM Table WHERE Checked='N' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1
) = 'N'
```

SQL evaluates step by step in a well-defined order. In this case, the subquery evaluates first because it's *uncorrelated*, i.e. it doesn't refer to any variables from the outer query.

The subquery finds the first row in `id` order where 'Checked' is 'N', and as the SELECT list contains the field `Checked`, that means the subquery will be substituted for the value `N`. Effectively it does nothing (except it might be `NULL` instead of `N` if no rows matched).

So now you have:

```
UPDATE Table SET Checked='Y' WHERE 'N' = 'N';
```

Starting to see what went wrong?

`'N' = 'N'` is always going to be true. So the `WHERE` clause is always true, and you might as well have written an unconstrained update.

```
UPDATE Table SET Checked='Y';
```

### How to fix it

You're trying to find the first row where `checked` is `n` and set `checked` to `y`. You need to *connect* these two parts using the primary key. Find the `id` you want to update, then use that to constrain the update.

Others have already written the text of that query, so I won't repeat it here. Hopefully you now understand those answers, though.

Comment: Thx, it was really helpful. My biggest mistake was that I tried to use the fromer command to build new and finally it didn't have sense.

Comment: you should have added the correct query for completeness

Answer (score 3):

Mention that if you have the concurrent requests you need to handle with transactions, for example -

```sql
UPDATE Table SET Checked='Y' WHERE ID =(SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Checked='N' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED)
```

if you want to skip locked rows

Comment: Why would we need to skip locked rows, can you provide some context/insight?

Answer (score -2):

Example of mssql:

```
UPDATE Table SET Checked='Y' 
WHERE ID =(SELECT top 1 ID FROM Table WHERE Checked='N')
```

Example of oracle:

```
UPDATE Table SET Checked='Y' 
WHERE ID =(SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Checked='N' and rownum<2)
```