# is it possible to update limit 1 when using rust diesel

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I want to update a table rows flag in PostgreSQL 13 when using rust diesel `diesel = { version = "2.0.4", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }`, this is the code looks like:

```
pub fn pick_task() -> CvGen{
    use crate::model::diesel::cv::cv_schema::cv_gen::dsl::*;
    let predicate = crate::model::diesel::cv::cv_schema::cv_gen::gen_status.eq(0);
    let result = diesel::update(cv_gen.filter(predicate))
        .set(
            gen_status.eq(1)
        )
        .get_result::<CvGen>(&mut get_connection())
        .expect("unable to update ren result");
    return result;
}
```

Now I am facing a issue that I just want to update one row althrough there is many rows match the filter. what should I to? I have read the official document from https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/dsl/fn.update.html and https://diesel.rs/guides/all-about-updates.html but did not found any clue about how to implement the update rows limit. is it possible to update with limit when using rust diesel?

Comment: Change the filter: Add for example the primary key to tell the database exactly what record it should update.

Comment: I just want to update a record matched the filter, I want to fetch a random row that matches the filter, should I select one row first and then update?

Comment: Select that random row first or use a subquery in your update statement to find that single row.

Comment: seems have to do like that, select and update are not atomatic, should use the transaction to handle the multi thread update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not nicely, partially because SQL doesn't make it nice.

Diesel only produces SQL statements and if the answers from [SQL How to Update only first Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258250/sql-how-to-update-only-first-row) are to be believed, the only way to achieve that goal is by using a subquery with `LIMIT 1`.

Diesel does support subqueries but unfortunately not if the subquery uses a same table as the parent, otherwise this would be roughly the equivalent:

```sql
UPDATE cv_gen
SET gen_status = 0 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM cv_gen WHERE gen_status = 1 LIMIT 1);
```

```rust
// DOES NOT WORK
let result = diesel::update(cv_gen)
    .filter(id.nullable().eq(cv_gen.filter(gen_status.eq(0)).select(id).single_value()))
    .set(gen_status.eq(1))
    .get_result::<CvGen>(&mut get_connection())
    .expect("unable to update ren result");
```

The way to actually do this then would be to write the SQL yourself with [`sql_query`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/fn.sql_query.html) or do this in two steps: one query to get an element to update, one to update that element.